# CSS3: right angled triangle with bow/arc

Tags: css, geometry

I'm trying to make a right angled triangle in CSS3, that part I have. But how can I make ith with arc/bow? (I'm sorry I don't how to best translate it to english).

This is what I need to have:

[image]

Is this possible? And how can I do it?

If I have that I'm happy, but I would be really really happy, if you guys could also tell me how to make it slide out from the bottom, so that the top slides out from the bottom. If you also know that, that would be great! But it's not my main question at the moment :-)

Comment: I think it would be much simpler to do this with a little SVG graphic.

Comment: agreed with @Sirko. Stuff like this shouldn't be done in CSS. And to be honest, I doubt whether it *can* be done in CSS. Use SVG instead.

Comment: Oke, I will also look into that, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done by applying a `border-radius` to an overlaying element.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/w94Uq/2/)

```
.angled-triangle {
    background-color:orange;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-left:5px;
    background-clip:content-box;
}

.angled-triangle::before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:white; /*same as element's parent background*/
    border-bottom-right-radius: 99% 90%;
    left:5px; /*push edge out of element*/
}
```

Tested in latest Chrome and Firefox. Feel free to adapt the values as necessary.

Only drawback for this approach is that you need to apply the same `background-color` to `::before` as the element parent's background, which is not always viable (e.g. `body` with background image). Check the update below for another method that does not have this limitation.

### *Update*

Another viable method is using a radial-gradient background. This method does not have issues with arbitrary elements' background unlike the method above, as this one uses a `transparent` color to fill the "blank" area.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/w94Uq/10/)

```
.angled-triangle {
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(0 0, transparent 70%, orange 71.5%);
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(0 0, transparent 70%, orange 71.5%);
    background-image: radial-gradient(top left, transparent 70%, orange 71.5%);
    background-position: 5px 0px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Above, `orange` represents the color you want the triangle to be. The `1.5%` between transparent and orange is just "easing", so that the border doesn't look pixelated. This is missing `-ms` and `-o` vendor prefixes as I haven't tested in those browsers.

Comment: `<kbd>` tags are used to denote user input. Please don't use them for JSFiddle links.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly makes sense, noted. `=]`

Comment: Thanks! I'm still new to css3 animations and making figure stuff, so thanks for helping out! And so fast! I choose the first approach, because it looked better/smoother in my browser (chrome on mac).